# G+ Sign In Getting Started results in "An internal error occurred"

Tags: android, android-studio, google-plus, google-play-services

I've been trying to get G+ Sign-In implemented on my sample Android app, but keep getting the same problem.

I've gone through this:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started

and this:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

When I run it, I click on the "G+ Sign in" button.  I then pick an account, and click OK.  Then I see a Toast that says "An internal error occurred"

That account picker and subsequent Toast happens at this line:

```
startIntentSenderForResult(mConnectionResult.getResolution().getIntentSender(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
```

I'm using Android Studio 0.8.2.  The Project is okay, and with the correct debug certificate (I got Maps v2 to work using the same package name).

This is mostly copy/paste from the two above URLs, so no typos.

Any suggestions?  Many thanks, I'm so stuck.

Source code below:

build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.OptimizedPrime.gplussample"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.OptimizedPrime.gplussample" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_my.xml (Layout file)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MyActivity.java file

```
package com.OptimizedPrime.gplussample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;


public class MyActivity extends Activity implements
        View.OnClickListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    /* Track whether the sign-in button has been clicked so that we know to resolve
     * all issues preventing sign-in without waiting.
     */
    private boolean mSignInClicked;

    /* Store the connection result from onConnectionFailed callbacks so that we can
     * resolve them when the user clicks sign-in.
     */

    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
    /* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

    /* Client used to interact with Google APIs. */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /* A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents
     * us from starting further intents.
     */
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .build();
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            // Store the ConnectionResult so that we can use it later when the user clicks
            // 'sign-in'.
            mConnectionResult = result;

            if (mSignInClicked) {
                // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to resolve all
                // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }

            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button
                && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }

    }

    /* A helper method to resolve the current ConnectionResult error. */
    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                //************************************
                //THE ERROR SHOWS UP AFTER THIS STATEMENT:
                startIntentSenderForResult(mConnectionResult.getResolution().getIntentSender(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
                //************************************
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
                // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There may be some information in the logcat output (of the whole system, not just your app)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was very simple... I needed to fill out the required fields in the Consent Screen of the Project in the Google Developers Console.  Specifically, Email Address and Product Name.  After I filled them out, the app ran with no problems.

Maps v2 ran without the Consent Screen being filled out, so I assumed the same applies to G+ Sign-In.  But that assumption did not hold true.

So, if you get "An internal error occurred" and you swear you did all the steps on the guide, go check your Consent Screen first.  The guide does not explicitly talk about the Consent Screen.